# Is there a way to view LINQ Generated query expressions in CRM Dynamics?

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm

Considering the fact LINQ queries in CRM Dynamics are translated into query expressions ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328028(v=crm.7).aspx)):

> [...] The OrganizationServiceContext class contains an underlying LINQ
>   query provider that translates LINQ queries from Microsoft Visual C#
>   or Microsoft Visual Basic .NET syntax into the query API used by
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM. [...]

Is there a way to see the generated query expressions (As it's possible to see the generated SQL query in Linq-to-Sql or Linq-to-Entities)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the query object and then convert that to a FetchXML query to get a printable query. This will work with both early-bound and late-bound queries.

From: https://pogo69.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/crm-linq-provider-converting-expressions-to-queryexpression-andor-fetchxml/

```
var connectionString = @"SET YOUR CONNECTION STRING";

var service = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);   

using (var xrm = service.OrganizationServiceProxy)
{

    OrganizationServiceContext orgContext =
                new OrganizationServiceContext(xrm);

    var query = from c in orgContext.CreateQuery("contact")
                join a in orgContext.CreateQuery("account")
                    on c["contactid"] equals a["primarycontactid"]
                where (String)c["lastname"] == "Wilcox" ||
                    (String)c["lastname"] == "Andrews"
                where ((String)a["address1_telephone1"]).Contains("(206)")
                    || ((String)a["address1_telephone1"]).Contains("(425)")
                select new
                {
                    Contact = new
                    {
                        FirstName = c["firstname"],
                        LastName = c["lastname"]
                    },
                    Account = new
                    {
                        Address1_Telephone1 = a["address1_telephone1"]
                    }
                };

    IQueryProvider queryProvider = query.Provider;      

    MethodInfo translateMethodInfo = queryProvider.GetType().GetMethod("Translate");
    QueryExpression queryEx = (QueryExpression)translateMethodInfo.Invoke(queryProvider, new object[] { query.Expression });        

    QueryExpressionToFetchXmlRequest reqConvertToFetchXml = new QueryExpressionToFetchXmlRequest { Query = queryEx };
    QueryExpressionToFetchXmlResponse respConvertToFetchXml = (QueryExpressionToFetchXmlResponse)xrm.Execute(reqConvertToFetchXml);

    Console.WriteLine("To FetchXML:" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
    Console.WriteLine(respConvertToFetchXml.FetchXml);
```

Alternatively you could use Fiddler to capture the actual query text sent in the SOAP message. I've done this before and haven't found it any more valuable than the FetchXml.